# How can I achieve this layout css

Tags: css

Hi there I know that is a silly question but I couldn't find a solution for this case, my css skills are not good :(.

How can I achieve the layout below.
The text should wrap at the end of the container(div,span,whatever)

```
 ---- --------------------------
|URL:|thissdfsisalongurasdsdfrea|
 ----|allyyyyyyyyyyylonggggggggg|  
     |sdddfasdfsdfasdfsadfsdfsds|
     |--------------------------|
```

Comment: Thnx Isaac that is it. Put it as Answer so I can give you credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tmqCR/

A few of these responses have what you need. I think this has everything together though.

Comment: Glad you posted this as an answer too. I saw your comment, but now I can give you the upvote you deserve and delete my own answer, which doesn't break non-spaced text. :(

Answer (score 2):

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="url">
     URL:
   </div>
   <div class="text">
   Lorem Ipsum dolor
   Lorem Ipsum dolor
   Lorem Ipsum dolor
   Lorem Ipsum dolor
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.url {
  float:left;
  width:60px;
}
.text {
  float:left;
  width:200px;
}
.clear {
   clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/FEZaJ/

The URL - Float it left;

Comment: I need that text to be wraped

Comment: when you add a little more content the float wraps around and it breaks

Comment: the text doesnt have empty spaces or characters that force the text to be breaked.

Answer (score 0):

The [media element](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/). Really breaks down to float: left; on the first element and overflow hidden on the second.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i m created this like one.

**Css**

```
.url {
    float: left;
    width: 75px;
    background:pink;
}

.description{
    float: left;
    width: 175px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align:justify;
    background:lightgreen;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="url">URL:</div>

<div class="description">thissdfsisalongurasdsdfreaallyyyyyyyyyyylongggggggggsdddfasdfsdfasdfsadfsdfsds</div>​
```

Live demo [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/tmqCR/25/) http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/tmqCR/25/